# normally should never public subclass vector<> but what if just convenient methods?

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector

**This is NOT a duplicate of "Thou shalt not inherit from std::vector" which is asking about adding "algorithms" not methods.**

Obviously there'd be a slicing problem if there were extra members, but there aren't.

There could be some other unexpected behavior if any methods were overiden, but they're not.

The spec says that deleting an object via a base-class pointer with a non-virtual destructor is undefined, but assume I have the self-control not to do that and that if I do, my implementation silently succeeds (as I assume all would; any known exceptions?)

There seems to be no problem with ref's or assignments to std vectors as the only things lost would be the additional methods.

Just off the cuff ideas for new methods that I find myself repeating constantly:

```
T& allow( size_t x ) { // grows the vector when necessary.
    if ( size() <= x )
        resize( x+1 );
}

T& ok( size_t x ) { // get lvalue, growing the vector when necessary.
    allow( x );
    return operator[]( x );
}

int size() { // return type is int, which is much more convenient; limits you to
             // MAXINT elements but enough for all code I've written in 26 years.
    return (int) vector<T>::size();
}

T& back( int i = 0 ) { // gives you back element, or indexed, gives Nth back.
    return operator[]( size() - i - 1 );
}
```

Comment: The "right solution" is to use free functions if you just want to add some additional methods.

Comment: fair enough but why?  Any reason besides  being technically undefined behavior?

Comment: "The spec seems to say that deriving a class with a non-virtual destructor is undefined: Why so?" - It doesn't say that - it says deleting a derived object through a base pointer is undefined if the base destructor is not virtual.

Comment: @SwissFrank Actually not UB. It's perfectly well defined (excepting weird implementations; I'm unsure if `std::vector` is allowed to be `final` for instance). As for why, [this CppCon 2017 talk](https://youtu.be/WLDT1lDOsb4) explains it

Comment: Personally, I prefer the postfix function call syntax (the member function call syntax), and I am waiting for the day that the proposals which would allow for this get through.

Comment: the general rule of thumb is to prefer [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance). The link provides several reasons why.

Answer (score 1):

[expr.delete/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.delete#3):

> In a single-object delete expression, if the static type of the object to be deleted is different from its dynamic type and the selected deallocation function (see below) is not a destroying operator delete, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted and the static type shall have a virtual destructor or the behavior is undefined. In an array delete expression, if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.